# MongoDB unwind output, grabbing one string

Tags: mongodb

```
"_id": "Long_ID_Stuff"
"GFV" : "user001"
"hf": "NA"
"h" : {
    "totalSamples" : 16,
    "hist" : [
     ["US",16]]
    "newEvent" :[
        ["US", NumberLong("654654654654")]
                ]
     }
```

I am trying to pull out just the "US" portion of this document in a query and so far it has been giving me nothing.

My query thus far is:

```
db.x_collection.aggregate([{$unwind :"$h.hist"},{$match : { m:"TOP_COUNTRIES"}},{$match: {"h.lastUpdate":{$gt:1446336000000}}},{$match: {"h.hist":"US"}}]).pretty()
```

Do I need to do a `$unwind: $h`, then `$unwind: $h.hist`?

Comment: Can you give us your full sample document? Right now your query makes no sense on the given document (which also isn't even syntactically correct). Also can you put some line breaks in your query? Its really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Without a little more information this is my best guess at what you are looking for. Given that the collection you are aggregating is the "h" collection.

```
db.x_collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$h.hist"},
  { $match : 
    { h.hist : "US" },
    { lastUpdate: { $gt:1446336000000 }},
    { m: "TOP_COUNTRIES" }
  }
]).pretty();
```

if "h" is an array you will need to add this:

```
{ $unwind : $h },
```

Comment: since the information is in an array in h.hist do i need to unwind them separately or is it even possible?  All the documentation that I could find was in regards to unwinding one level of arrays.

Comment: @Justin if "h" is an array then you will need to unwind it also. If not then you should only need to unwind "$h.hist". I will edit to reflect this.